# Why is there a compiler warning on this statement?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In a standard iPhone app I'm displaying an image picker on top of a table view.  The code works fine (I believe ;-)), but I get a compiler warning when setting the image picker delegate to be the table view controller (ChoiceController).
[image]
ChoiceController is defined to implement the delegate:

`@interface ChoiceController : UITableViewController 
                       <UIActionSheetDelegate,
                                UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>`
 
and clearly does become the delegate, because it receives all the appropriate actions.

I've tried casting ChoiceController, i.e. self, to UIImagePickerControllerDelegate but I get the same result.

Insights welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in the warning text that the delegate has to be `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`, but also `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

It's defined so:
`@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> delegate`

In your case, it works fine because all `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods are optional. Had that not been the case, the app would have crashed with `unknown selector send to instance` exception.

You should implement the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol. If you do not need any of the methods declared there, and they are indeed optional, do not implement them.